# I have forms 1040x, 1040, Schedule B (form 1040a or 1040), 1099-R. How should I staple them and send?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040x

I need to amend my tax return in order to include 1099-R (got money from 401(k)). TurboTax gave me 3 forms - 1040X, 1040, Schedule B (form 1040A or 1040).
How should I staple my amended tax return?
Should I staple all forms together or separately? 
Where should I include form 1099-R?
Should I include my W-2 again?

Answer (score 1):

The [IRS instructions](https://www.irs.gov/uac/everything-you-need-to-know-about-making-federal-tax-payments) do not specify how to connect the forms, just that you should not staple the *check* to the form (likely because it goes to a different location for processing).

I have always either stapled or paper-clipped them together, however I would assume that the receiving department does not care, otherwise it would be explicit in the instructions.